# All Annotation is not visible to user in MKMapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, annotations, mkmapview, mapkit

I am using `MKMapView` and have added a number of annotation pins to the map. All annotation belong to different country, so i do not able to set all annotation visible to user.

Please do try using below latitude and longitude for annotation.

`First annotation Latitude:`23.029690

`First annotation Longitude:` 72.527359

`Second annotation Latitude:`34.210855

`Second annotation Longitude:` -118.622636

**Code for add annotation to mapview.**

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[dicObjects valueForKey:K_Latitude] doubleValue], [[dicObjects valueForKey:K_Longitude] doubleValue]);
MyCustomAnnotation *myCustomAnnotation = [[MyCustomAnnotation alloc]initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@           ",[dicObjects valueForKey:K_Title]] Subtitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dicObjects valueForKey:K_SubTitle]] andDescritpion:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dicObjects valueForKey:K_TitelDes]] withLocation:coordinate andImageName:[dicObjects valueForKey:K_Rating] andTagValue:intTempCounter];
[mapViewPledgeList addAnnotation:myCustomAnnotation];
```

**MyCustomAnnotation.h**

```
@interface MyCustomAnnotation : NSObject<MKAnnotation>

@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *title;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *subTitle;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *titleDescritpion;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *strImageName;
@property  int intTagValue;


- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)newTitle Subtitle:(NSString *)subTitle andDescritpion:(NSString *)titleDescritpion withLocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)location andTagValue:(int) intTag;
- (MKAnnotationView *)annotationView;
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)newTitle Subtitle:(NSString *)subTitle andDescritpion:(NSString *)titleDescritpion withLocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)location andImageName:(NSString*) strImageName andTagValue:(int) intTag;
@end
```

**MyCustomAnnotation.m**

```
#import "MyCustomAnnotation.h"

@implementation MyCustomAnnotation


#pragma mark - Custom Annotation View Setup
- (MKAnnotationView *)annotationView{

    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:self reuseIdentifier:K_ID_CUSTOM_ANNOTATION];
    annotationView.enabled = YES;
    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
    annotationView.image = kImage(_strImageName);

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 23, 23);
    button.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    button.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
    [button setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"NextArrow"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = button;

    return annotationView;
}

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)newTitle Subtitle:(NSString *)subTitle andDescritpion:(NSString *)titleDescritpion withLocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)location andImageName:(NSString*) strImageName andTagValue:(int) intTag{

    self = [super init];

    if(self){
        _title = newTitle;
        _subTitle = subTitle;
        _titleDescritpion = titleDescritpion;
        _coordinate = location;


        if ([strImageName intValue] == 1) {
            _strImageName = @"MapViewPinRed";

        }else if([strImageName intValue] == 2){
            _strImageName = @"MapViewPinOrange";

        }else if ([strImageName intValue] == 3){
            _strImageName = @"MapViewPinYellow";

        }else if ([strImageName intValue] == 4){
            _strImageName = @"MapViewPinLightGreen";

        }else{
            _strImageName = @"MapViewPinGreen";

        }
    }

    return self;
}

    @end
```

**I was try below solution but it is not working.**

1) Using `MKMapRectUnion`

```
 MKMapRect zoomRect = MKMapRectNull;
    for (id <MKAnnotation> annotation in mapViewPledgeList.annotations)
    {
        MKMapPoint annotationPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(annotation.coordinate);
        MKMapRect pointRect = MKMapRectMake(annotationPoint.x, annotationPoint.y, 0.1, 0.1);
        zoomRect = MKMapRectUnion(zoomRect, pointRect);
    }
    [mapViewPledgeList setVisibleMapRect:zoomRect animated:YES];
```

2) Using `showAnnotations`

```
 [mapViewPledgeList showAnnotations:mapViewPledgeList.annotations animated:YES];
```

**Issue:-** suggest any solution so all annotation keep visible to user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q] All annotation keep visible to user.

- Unfortunately, it is not possible to set minimum zoom level less then the MKMapView minimum limit.
- Also in apple official map application below point is not visible at same time

  `First annotation Latitude:`23.029690

  `First annotation Longitude:` 72.527359

  `Second annotation Latitude:` 34.210855

  `Second annotation Longitude:` -118.622636

**Note: We can't zoom in Map View after it's minimum limit.**

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to add annotation to the map. Maybe this could be the problem

```
[self.mapView addAnnotation:point];
```

Comment: Annotation is already placed in Map but it all annotation is not visible at a same time.

Comment: I misunderstand question @Hiteshsurani

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the `mapView` the correct value of `region` which is of type `MKCoordinateRegion`. You need to do some calculations before you could tell the `mapView` to show correct `region`.

A. Find out value of following variables by lopping through all available coordinates array.

```
CLLocationDegrees minLatitude = // To be calculated
CLLocationDegrees maxLatitude = // To be calculated

CLLocationDegrees minLongitude = // To be calculated
CLLocationDegrees maxLongitude = // To be calculated
```

B. Calculate center coordinate for map.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D center = 
CLLocationCoordinate2DMake((maxLatitude+minLatitude)/2, (maxLongitude+minLongitude)/2);
```

C. Calculate `latitudeDelta` and `longitudeDelta` values -

```
CLLocationDegrees latitudeDelta = ABS(maxLatitude-minLatitude)*2;
CLLocationDegrees longitudeDelta = ABS(maxLongitude-minLongitude)*2;
```

D. Calculate `span`

```
MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latitudeDelta, longitudeDelta);
```

E. Calculate `region` and tell your `mapView` to show this -

```
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(center, span);
[mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
```

> There are a few more considerations while doing this like how much max/min `latitudeDelta` and `longitudeDelta` you wish to support. That can be applied to Step C when you are calculating the values.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inform mapview to perfect region so all the annotation pins are visible.

below swift code help you.

```
extension MKMapView {
    func getAllAnnotationExpectCurrntLocation() -> [MKAnnotation] {
        var arrAnnotion: [MKAnnotation] = self.annotations
        arrAnnotion = arrAnnotion.filter { $0 !== self.userLocation }
        return arrAnnotion
    }

    func zoomToFitMapAnnotations() {
        guard self.annotations.count != 0 else {
            return
        }

        var topLeftCordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -90, longitude: 180)
        var bottomRightCordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 90, longitude: -180)

        for ann in self.getAllAnnotationExpectCurrntLocation() {
            topLeftCordinate.longitude = fmin(topLeftCordinate.longitude, ann.coordinate.longitude)
            topLeftCordinate.latitude = fmax(topLeftCordinate.latitude, ann.coordinate.latitude)

            bottomRightCordinate.longitude = fmax(bottomRightCordinate.longitude, ann.coordinate.longitude)
            bottomRightCordinate.latitude = fmin(bottomRightCordinate.latitude, ann.coordinate.latitude)
        }

        let latitude = topLeftCordinate.latitude - ((topLeftCordinate.latitude - bottomRightCordinate.latitude) * 0.5)
        let longitude = topLeftCordinate.longitude + ((bottomRightCordinate.longitude - topLeftCordinate.longitude) * 0.5)

        let latitudeDelta = fabs(topLeftCordinate.latitude - bottomRightCordinate.latitude) * 1.1
        let longitudeDelta = fabs(bottomRightCordinate.longitude - topLeftCordinate.longitude) * 1.1
        let span: MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: latitudeDelta, longitudeDelta: longitudeDelta)

        let centerCordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
        let region: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: centerCordinate, span: span)
        let newregion = self.regionThatFits(region)
        self.setRegion(newregion, animated: true)

    }
}
```

Comment: tell me issues regard 'zoomToFitMapAnnotations' to fix the map to see all annotation on Map.

Comment: Unable to zoom in mapview after minimum Zoom level